# Highlight matches in string by color

Tags: string-manipulation

Suppose I have `"Some potentially multiline string"`. Is there a way I can have all instances of some matching word, say `"potentially"`, to be colored red, so that the new string shows up as:

```
"Some potentially multiline string"
```

but with `potentially` in red?